# How to pass an array to where condition in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using `CodeIgniter` in my application. I have a code like this

> $this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT PreferenceParentID
>   FROM '.$table.' WHERE EntityID='.$shop_id.')', NULL, FALSE);

I want to pass an `array` instead of `$shop_id`.

Like

```
$arr = array(1,3,5);

WHERE EntityID='. $arr.'
```

it will be equal to

```
WHERE (EntityID='. $arr[0].' OR EntityID='. $arr[1].' OR EntityID='. $arr[2].')
```

Because I want to check with multiple shop id's. What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `IN` clause like

```
$this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (
    SELECT PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.' 
    WHERE EntityID IN ('.implode(",", $array).'))',
    NULL, FALSE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
'SELECT PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.' WHERE EntityID IN ('.implode(',', $arr_id).')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
WHERE EntityID IN('.implode(',', $arr).')
```